# How can I make `avahi` work outside when `netatalk` running inside docker on `ubuntu`?

Tags: ubuntu, docker, avahi, timemachine

## Environment:

#### Host PC:

- Windows 7 ultimate 64bit
- VMware: VMware Workstation 12 Pro
- VMware Network: Bridge
- Inside VMware

  - OS: Ubuntu 16.04.1 amd64 Desktop
  - avahi-daemon: 0.6.32 -------> installation via apt
  - docker: 1.12.4 -------> installation via binary package
  - docker image: cptactionhank/netatalk:latest

#### Test PC:

- OS X 10.10

#### Reference:

[cptactionhank/netatalk](https://github.com/cptactionhank/docker-netatalk)

#### Statement:

I want to set my VMware's ubuntu system as a `netatalk` server (`time machine`).

- run `avahi` & `netatalk` both in docker -> **SUCCESS**

  just like:

  `1. systemctl stop avahi-daemon ------> stop avahi server
      2. dockerd -H tcp://127.0.0.1:6666 -------> run docker server
      3. docker -H tcp://127.0.0.1:6666 run --privileged --net "host" --env AVAHI=1 cptactionhank/netatalk:latest ------> create a new netatalk container with running avahi`

  `test pc`'s `time machine` can find this service immediately.
- run `avahi` on host pc, run `netatalk` in docker ------> **FAILED**

  just like:

  `1. systemctl start avahi-daemon ------> start avahi server
      2. dockerd -H tcp://127.0.0.1:6666 -------> run docker server
      3. docker -H tcp://127.0.0.1:6666 run --privileged --net "host" cptactionhank/netatalk:latest ------> create a new netatalk container without avahi`

  `test pc`'s `time machine` can not find this service.

  I've tried many ways just like create `afpd.service`[reference](https://github.com/odarriba/docker-timemachine) under */etc/avahi/service* folder, or add some new command parameters like *-v /var/lib/dbus:/var/lib/dbus -v /var/run/dbus:/var/run/dbus -v /run/systemd:/run/systemd -v /bin/systemctl:/bin/systemctl -v /etc/systemd/system:/etc/systemd/system*, but it still didn't work.

#### Thanks, ^_^

Comment: I have solved this problem, editing command line like this: `docker -H tcp://127.0.0.1:6666 run --privileged --net "host" -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /run/systemd:/run/systemd -v /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket:/var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket  cptactionhank/netatalk:latest`.